# Timeout::Error after new browser window opens

Tags: timeout, watir, watir-webdriver

When I click this label:

```
<label>&nbsp;Row&nbsp;</label>
```

using this Watir code

```
br.frame(:name, "frameset").frame(:name, "main_content").span(:class=>"tabtext", :text=>/Row/).click
```

a new browser window opens, but I get this error message:

```
Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:81:in `response_for'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:43:in `request'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:590:in `raw_execute'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:568:in `execute'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:350:in `clickElement'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:34:in `click'
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.5.3/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:107:in `click'
from (irb):75
from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I do not see anything strange in any browser window. The new window opens pretty quickly. I am not sure why I got the timeout error. Is there something I can do to get rid of it? Or is the page just to slow to respond?

If I rescue the exception I can close the new window and continue with the script, but I would like to avoid rescuing the error.

Environment: Mac OS X 10.7.3, Firefox 10.0.1, ruby 1.9.3p0, selenium-webdriver 2.19.0, watir-webdriver 0.5.3

**Update:**

I am pretty sure the problem is caused by the window being open by `window.showModalDialog`. For example, this times out:

```
b.execute_script "window.showModalDialog('http://google.com');"
```

I will investigate more and update the question. Looks like Selenium does not have support for `window.showModalDialog` yet: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=284

Comment: It's going to be hard to help with this unless you can create an example that will let us reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you already increased your driver timeout?

Comment: could this be related to the fact it is opening a new window and not just navigating within the browser?  is .click expecting the local browser to do something and timing out because it isn't?

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem here. @jarib suggested (via e-mail) a few things I should try. I will post updates as soon as I know more.

Comment: @adamreed: For now I have decreased the default timeout, rescued the timeout exception and continued with the execution of the script.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden: I am not sure yet if the timeout is application or watir problem.

Comment: I remember a very old topic regarding vanilla watir performance drags when using nested frames, so I would not be surprised if that is at least part to blame.

Comment: @adamreed: yes, the site is really slow, clicking the span takes 5-10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are clicking a span, which is not something that would normally respond to a click in basic HTML, it makes me suspect there is some kind of javascript code being executed in response perhaps to it seeing an onclick event.

Have you tried using `.fire_event('onclick')` instead of `.click`  to see if that would still invoke the code that opens the new page but avoids the timeout?

Comment: If you were on windows I would suggest perhaps using the Fiddler2 HTTP proxy to watch the traffic and see if there is some request being made of the server that is not fulfilled.  Not sure what the equivalent would be for a mac or *nix system.

Comment: Good idea. If the client decides to fund further investigation I will try that. For now I just rescue the timeout exception and continue with the script. It was the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Looks like `window.showModalDialog` is causing the problem, I have updated the question.